# Deadlocking issue in parallel batch processing (Invoice Posting ax 2009)

Tags: sql, dynamics-ax-2009, database-deadlocks

I am getting an error "Cannot select a record in SalesParmSubTable.
Deadlock, where one or more users have simultaneously locked the whole table or part of it".

I used sql profiler for getting the deadlock trace. Can someone please help to rectify it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<deadlock-list>
   <deadlock victim="process58d048">
      <process-list>
         <process id="process58d048" taskpriority="0" logused="5784" waitresource="PAGE: 16:1:16714223" waittime="1587" ownerId="207752233" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2016-05-07T07:58:32.533" XDES="0x52376d950" lockMode="S" schedulerid="4" kpid="10860" status="suspended" spid="159" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="1" lastbatchstarted="2016-05-07T07:58:32.553" lastbatchcompleted="2016-05-07T07:58:32.553" clientapp="Microsoft Dynamics AX" hostname="*********" hostpid="19816" loginname="************" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="207752233" currentdb="16" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
            <executionStack>
               <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="100" sqlhandle="0x02000000d3d2cf1665ba9e17ee49d6dd9bc2fbf295ad7168">SELECT A.DEL_SALESID,A.SALESNAME,A.PARMID,A.ORIGSALESID,A.TABLEREFID,A.DEL_ORIGTABLEREFID,A.JOURNALREFTABLEID,A.JOURNALREFRECID,A.SUBID,A.CREATEDDATETIME,A.CREATEDBY,A.RECVERSION,A.RECID FROM SALESPARMSUBTABLE A WHERE ((A.DATAAREAID=@P1) AND (A.PARMID=@P2)) AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'x' FROM SALESPARMLINE B WHERE ((B.DATAAREAID=@P3) AND (((B.PARMID=A.PARMID) AND (B.TABLEREFID=A.TABLEREFID)) AND (B.ORIGSALESID=A.ORIGSALESID)))) ORDER BY A.DATAAREAID,A.PARMID,A.DEL_SALESID</frame>
               <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">unknown</frame>
            </executionStack>
            <inputbuf>(@P1 nvarchar(5),@P2 nvarchar(21),@P3 nvarchar(5))SELECT A.DEL_SALESID,A.SALESNAME,A.PARMID,A.ORIGSALESID,A.TABLEREFID,A.DEL_ORIGTABLEREFID,A.JOURNALREFTABLEID,A.JOURNALREFRECID,A.SUBID,A.CREATEDDATETIME,A.CREATEDBY,A.RECVERSION,A.RECID FROM SALESPARMSUBTABLE A WHERE ((A.DATAAREAID=@P1) AND (A.PARMID=@P2)) AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'x' FROM SALESPARMLINE B WHERE ((B.DATAAREAID=@P3) AND (((B.PARMID=A.PARMID) AND (B.TABLEREFID=A.TABLEREFID)) AND (B.ORIGSALESID=A.ORIGSALESID)))) ORDER BY A.DATAAREAID,A.PARMID,A.DEL_SALESID</inputbuf>
         </process>
         <process id="process572988" taskpriority="0" logused="5800" waitresource="PAGE: 16:1:16714223" waittime="1576" ownerId="207752211" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2016-05-07T07:58:32.530" XDES="0x865e1950" lockMode="S" schedulerid="3" kpid="21628" status="suspended" spid="154" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="1" lastbatchstarted="2016-05-07T07:58:32.563" lastbatchcompleted="2016-05-07T07:58:32.560" clientapp="Microsoft Dynamics AX" hostname="*********" hostpid="19816" loginname="*********" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="207752211" currentdb="16" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
            <executionStack>
               <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="100" sqlhandle="0x02000000d3d2cf1665ba9e17ee49d6dd9bc2fbf295ad7168">SELECT A.DEL_SALESID,A.SALESNAME,A.PARMID,A.ORIGSALESID,A.TABLEREFID,A.DEL_ORIGTABLEREFID,A.JOURNALREFTABLEID,A.JOURNALREFRECID,A.SUBID,A.CREATEDDATETIME,A.CREATEDBY,A.RECVERSION,A.RECID FROM SALESPARMSUBTABLE A WHERE ((A.DATAAREAID=@P1) AND (A.PARMID=@P2)) AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'x' FROM SALESPARMLINE B WHERE ((B.DATAAREAID=@P3) AND (((B.PARMID=A.PARMID) AND (B.TABLEREFID=A.TABLEREFID)) AND (B.ORIGSALESID=A.ORIGSALESID)))) ORDER BY A.DATAAREAID,A.PARMID,A.DEL_SALESID</frame>
               <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">unknown</frame>
            </executionStack>
            <inputbuf>(@P1 nvarchar(5),@P2 nvarchar(21),@P3 nvarchar(5))SELECT A.DEL_SALESID,A.SALESNAME,A.PARMID,A.ORIGSALESID,A.TABLEREFID,A.DEL_ORIGTABLEREFID,A.JOURNALREFTABLEID,A.JOURNALREFRECID,A.SUBID,A.CREATEDDATETIME,A.CREATEDBY,A.RECVERSION,A.RECID FROM SALESPARMSUBTABLE A WHERE ((A.DATAAREAID=@P1) AND (A.PARMID=@P2)) AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'x' FROM SALESPARMLINE B WHERE ((B.DATAAREAID=@P3) AND (((B.PARMID=A.PARMID) AND (B.TABLEREFID=A.TABLEREFID)) AND (B.ORIGSALESID=A.ORIGSALESID)))) ORDER BY A.DATAAREAID,A.PARMID,A.DEL_SALESID</inputbuf>
         </process>
      </process-list>
      <resource-list>
         <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="16714223" dbid="16" objectname="AX2009_****.dbo.SALESPARMLINE" id="lock562bdb480" mode="IX" associatedObjectId="72057635944464384">
            <owner-list>
               <owner id="process572988" mode="IX" />
            </owner-list>
            <waiter-list>
               <waiter id="process58d048" mode="S" requestType="convert" />
            </waiter-list>
         </pagelock>
         <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="16714223" dbid="16" objectname="AX2009_****.dbo.SALESPARMLINE" id="lock562bdb480" mode="IX" associatedObjectId="72057635944464384">
            <owner-list>
               <owner id="process58d048" mode="IX" />
            </owner-list>
            <waiter-list>
               <waiter id="process572988" mode="S" requestType="convert" />
            </waiter-list>
         </pagelock>
      </resource-list>
   </deadlock>
</deadlock-list>
```

Comment: This seems to indicate the mentioned SELECT is part of a transaction where an update is going to happen. Could you confirm if indeed there is a (potential) update in the same transaction?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we can solve the deadlock issue by merely knowing a deadlock is occurring...we need to know why or what process is happening.

It looks like it's a cleanup operation or something with sales order posting, because it's looking for `SalesParmTable` records where the `SalesParmLine` records don't exist.  You can use that query to look for the select statement in code and work backwards to see what process is initiating it.

I'd think a better approach would be, when it's happening, find out what users are doing at the time.  Check batch jobs to see if two batch jobs are doing the same thing at the same time.

You may be able to find out what users/processes are causing it by following this blog:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/amitkulkarni/2011/08/10/finding-user-sessions-from-spid-in-dynamics-ax-2012/